# How to include Salesforce Object fields as AMPscript variables in emails sent from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I'm trying to use a Salesforce Object field as an AMPscript variable in an email, when the Salesforce Entry Event is used in a Journey Builder Interaction.

I've created a 'Salesforce Data' event (from the Define Entry Event modal when creating an entry event) using the CampaignMember Object as my Primary Event Object. I want to use the value of the `Id` field from the CampaignMember Salesforce Object (which I've included as a field in the Event Data when configuring the Event).

The following AMPscript block does not work (note, I am trying to set `@campaignMemberId` to equal the `Id` field from the CampaignMember Salesforce Object)

```
%%[
var @campaignMemberId, @Case, @CaseRow, @barcode

Set @campaignMemberId = Id
set @Case = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("CampaignMember","Coupon_Number__c","Id", "=", @campaignMemberId)
Set @CaseRow = Row(@Case, 1)
Set @barcode = FIELD(@CaseRow, "Coupon_Number__c")

]%%
```

What syntax should you use to define Salesforce fields in this context so they can be passed from the Event Source to the Email Activity?

Answer (score 6):

If you select a 'Salesforce Data' event or 'Salesforce Campaign Event' from the Define Entry Event modal when creating a Journey Builder Event, then the required Attribute Set(s) will be dynamically created in a new Attribute Group named 'Sales and Service Cloud'.

Open Contact Builder and check the Attribute name in the Attribute Set for the variable name to use in AMPScript. For example, in the screenshot below, the `Id` of the `Campaign Member` object is `CampaignMember:Id`.

[image: Sales and Service Cloud Attribute Group]

So, simply use `CampaignMember:Id` in your AMPscript:

```
%%[
var @campaignMemberId, @Case, @CaseRow, @barcode

Set @campaignMemberId = CampaignMember:Id
set @Case = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("CampaignMember","Coupon_Number__c","Id", "=", @campaignMemberId)
Set @CaseRow = Row(@Case, 1)
Set @barcode = FIELD(@CaseRow, "Coupon_Number__c")

]%%
```