# Ampscript - How to use Salesforce Data Event fields in Email templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

I have created a journey for the first time in Journey Builder, Salesforce Data event linking Leads (Standard). I then pressed the test button and it came up with an error which I found out was to to do with the personalisation string %%firstname%% (the only piece of personalisation in the email)

So I searched for some information and found the question on here: *[How to include Salesforce Object fields as AMPscript variables in emails sent from Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131234/how-to-include-salesforce-object-fields-as-ampscript-variables-in-emails-sent-fr)* When I go into Contact Builder I dont see any linked attributes, which from the question looks like I need to see so that I can check the names? Do I need to set anything else up to allow the attributes to get to the Contact Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to access Event data without changed data or additional data not present in the event, you just need to use the name of the field. For further data to be available in Contact Builder you need to set up Synchronized Data Sources, so the needed Salesforce Objects are synchronized automatically.

**Accessing event/journey data via AMPscript:**

*First you need to find out the column name of the data you like to access:*

1. Go to Email Studio -> Subscribers -> Data Extensions
2. Find the Data Extension created for your Salesforce Data Entry Event (starts with the name of your entry event)
3. Click on the Data Extension
4. Check out the column name containing the required data (e.g. `SalesforceObjectName__c:RelatedObject__r:Fieldname`)

*After that you can write this value to a variable in AMPscript using the following code:*

```
%%[
    Var @field
    Set @field = SalesforceObjectName__c:RelatedObject__r:Fieldname
]%%
```

**Information on setting up synchronized data sources:**

- [Marketing Cloud Connect](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/)
- [Data Sources](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/)
- [Data Integration for Your Account with Synchronized Data Sources](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/integrate_data_into_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources/)
- [Implement Synchronized Data Sources](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/integrate_data_into_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources/implement_synchronized_data_sources/)
- [Create Synchronized Data Sources](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources/)
- [Interact with Synchronized Data Sources](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/interact_with_synchronized_data_sources/)

Comment: That helps a lot - for some reason now when I go to the Contact Builder the Sales and Service 'bubble' appears...This only happened once I navigated following steps 1 I and checked the use for testing on one of the Data Extensions.