# Retrieving the object ID that trigger journey builder entry event by Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

- I created a journey with Salesforce data as entry source.
- The Salesforce data is based on new opportunity object creation and
  account is the entity who got injected to the journey.
- How to write an Ampscript to get the opportunity ID that trigger the journey?
- I usually use retrievesalesforceobject with subscriberkey to get
  lead/contact data, but in this case, I am not sure how to get the
  opportunity ID

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I did perform searches but was unable to find the answer, but now I found two similar threads

The answer is `Set @OpportunityId = Opportunity:Id`.

You can also find the Data Extension created for your Salesforce Data Entry Event at Email Studio -> Subscribers -> Data Extensions
and check out the column name containing the required data (e.g. `SalesforceObjectName__c:RelatedObject__r:Fieldname`

Reference:

- [How to include Salesforce Object fields as AMPscript variables in emails sent from Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131234/how-to-include-salesforce-object-fields-as-ampscript-variables-in-emails-sent-fr?rq=1)
- [Ampscript - How to use Salesforce Data Event fields in Email templates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180046/ampscript-how-to-use-salesforce-data-event-fields-in-email-templates?rq=1)