# AMPscript Lookup function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, data, marketing-cloud-connect

```
%%[ VAR @EventType, @DateTime, @Address
SET @EventType = Lookup("CampaignMember_Contact_Builder", "Event_Type__c", "ContactId", _subscriberkey)
SET @DateTime = Lookup("CampaignMember_Contact_Builder", "Event_Date__c", "ContactId", _subscriberkey)
SET @Address = Lookup("CampaignMember_Contact_Builder", "Address__c", "ContactId", _subscriberkey)]%%
```

Having trouble with my lookup function.  When called, these vars are not returning anything in preview. All data comes from Salesforce using the connector.

Comment: How are you calling the values?

Comment: Is this an email or a landing page?

Comment: @Data_Kid WHO: %%=v(@who)=%%
WHAT: %%=v(@EventType)=%%
WHEN: %%=v(@DateTime)=%%
WHERE: %%=v(@Address)=%%

Comment: @Data_Kid This is an email.

Comment: @Data_Kid  It works with one subscriber in preview but none of the others.  Have a feeling something is wonky with the Id's but can't figure out what's not registering with the system

Comment: Are you sure you have the data extension name?   Typically the synchronized data extensions are named like `ObjectName_Salesforce`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question depends on how your Data Extension is populated.

If it's a Synchronized Data Extension, then you can retrieve it like this:

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @sk

set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

output(concat("<br>sk: ",@sk))

set @rows = LookupRows("CampaignMember_Salesforce","ContactId", @sk)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    var @EventType, @DateTime, @Address
    set @row = row(@rows,1) 
    set @EventType = field(@row,"EventType")
    set @DateTime = field(@row,"DateTime")
    set @Address = field(@row,"Address")

    output(concat("<br>EventType: ",@eventType))
    output(concat("<br>DateTime: ",@DateTime))
    output(concat("<br>Address: ",@Address))

else

    output(concat("<br>no rows found"))

endif

]%%
```

Or you can retrieve it directly from Sales Cloud like this:

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @sk

set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

output(concat("<br>sk: ",@sk))

set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("CampaignMember","EventType,DateTime,Address","ContactId", "=", @sk)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    var @EventType, @DateTime, @Address
    set @row = row(@rows,1) 
    set @EventType = field(@row,"EventType")
    set @DateTime = field(@row,"DateTime")
    set @Address = field(@row,"Address")

    output(concat("<br>EventType: ",@eventType))
    output(concat("<br>DateTime: ",@DateTime))
    output(concat("<br>Address: ",@Address))

else

    output(concat("<br>no rows found"))

endif

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**How to include Salesforce Object fields as AMPscript variables in emails sent from Journey Builder**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/131235/5202)
- [**Synchronized Data Sources**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources/)
- [**AMPScript Lookup Examples**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)
- [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects()**](https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects)

Comment: The issue was because there was a one to many relationship to the Lookup DE and therefore it wasn't pulling the right row of data.  I'm now looking at ways I can identify the row that will be needed for that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [attribute value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) ampscript function to capture the `subscriberkey`.

eg

```
%%[ VAR @EventType, @DateTime, @Address , @SubscriberKey

SET @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @EventType = Lookup("CampaignMember_Contact_Builder", "Event_Type__c", "ContactId", @SubscriberKey)
SET @DateTime = Lookup("CampaignMember_Contact_Builder", "Event_Date__c", "ContactId", @SubscriberKey)
SET @Address = Lookup("CampaignMember_Contact_Builder", "Address__c", "ContactId", @SubscriberKey)]%%
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same results.

Comment: Try doing just `%%=v(@SusbcriberKey)=%%` in your preview to see if the ones that fail have null/ malformed value/ emailaddress. Are all your subscribers coming from salescloud? you might find that in some instances the subscriberkey is an emailaddress , therefore it wont map onto `ContactId` in `CampaignMember_Contact_Builder`

Comment: @StephanieWood the suggestion above

Comment: The subscriber key is showing up fine when I preview in the email showing as an 18 digit SF record id like it's supposed to.  Yes all our subscribers come from salesforce.  Any other ideas? I might have to take this to support. @Data_Kid

Comment: @StephanieWood Im all out of ideas sorry x